# How do I use the console fonts in normal applications?

Tags: fonts

The fonts available for use in the console can be found in **/usr/share/consolefonts/**, in files with the extension **.psf.gz**. Fontforge doesn't seem to know about them. I can convert them **bdf** format using **gbdfed** and in turn to **pcf** format using **bdftopcf**, but they are not available to applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK You cannot use those fonts in normal applications because they are not the right kind of font. These "console fonts" are purely bitmap fonts for use on the command line (specifically ttys and on boot, etc).

Fonts you would use in your applications are usually either truetype or opentype fonts, and another kind of bitmap font (I forgot the extension).

If pcf *is* supported by applications (I don't remember) you can copy the .pcf files to `/usr/share/fonts` and then restart your computer or update your font cache.

Comment: pcf is supported by applications but the translation from bdf to pcf via the method above doesn't work. psf to bdf does work however

Comment: @daithib8 what method? I didn't mention a method anywhere.